# tf.extract_image_patches for 3D images

Tags: tensorflow, keras, ssim, loss-function

[The documentation of tf.extract_image_patches](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/extract_image_patches)

It is only for 2D image, could it be expand to 3D images, which is useful for the implementation for SSIM loss function?

I cannot find the source code. There is a similar function `skimage.util.view_as_windows`, however, when I try to use this function with the tensorflow as backend in keras, there are errors. The transition from numpy array to tensor confused me a lot.